# issue in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => Name
            [B] => Email
            [C] => Phone
            [D] => Bank Name
            [E] => Cheque Number
            [F] => Cheque Date
            [G] => Amount
            [H] => Due On
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A] => Sri
            [B] => srimanta123@gmail.com
            [C] => 312313131
            [D] => SBI
            [E] => 32324234
            [F] => 9/19/13 19:00
            [G] => 121
            [H] => 7/12/13 15:00
        )

)
```

Now, I want to convert this above array to

```
Array
(

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => Sri
            [B] => srimanta123@gmail.com
            [C] => 312313131
            [D] => SBI
            [E] => 32324234
            [F] => 9/19/13 19:00
            [G] => 121
            [H] => 7/12/13 15:00
        )

)
```

by making use of php.

I am trying by using `array_shift()`. But by array_shift, I am not getting the exact output. By using this, I got the following output:

```
  Array
    (
        [A] => Name
        [B] => Email
        [C] => Phone
        [D] => Bank Name
        [E] => Cheque Number
        [F] => Cheque Date
        [G] => Amount
        [H] => Due On
    )
```

Please let me know how to do that.

Comment: Why on earth would you strip out the line breaks in your `print_r`? That's unreadable.

Comment: @ceejayoz Guessing it was copied from the browser rendering and not from page source.

Comment: Please view the page source in your browser, and copy the array `print_r()` dumps from threre. It will be _far_ easier for us to understand the structure with linebreaks intact

Comment: @jeroen thanks for formatting.

Comment: This does not help that much, you'd better paste from the page source.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Is it readable now? It has been edited already.

Comment: @Srimanta No that just added blockquote markup to get it to break lines on this screen. If you do it from page source, the array will be indented showing nesting, and with one element per line.

Comment: Please check whether it is readable or not.

Comment: @Srimanta There, that's better!@

Comment: Now please let me know how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) does the trick, but you have to realize that [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) modifies the original array and returns the shifted element.

So the result would be in your original array, not in the return value.

By the way, personally I would make sure that I get my data in an associative array so that the values of your first sub-array are the keys of the values in the second sub-array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working fine. Actually I made a mistake to store the array_shift() in one variable then print that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newArray = array_combine(array_values($array[0]), array_values($array[1]));
```

As noted, it's pretty hard to tell with the formatting. If you're having issues formatting try adding `<pre>` to the top of your page before the `print_r`.